# Android Studio okhttp3 response with empty arraylist

Tags: android

I am successfully using okhttp to GET a json from an API.  However the response is supposed to give me 4 things: status, links, schema, and a array (or arraylist) called "items"  Here's part of the sample response where I cut off for repetition:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "links": {
    "self": "http://localhost:64930/v1/suggestions?q=wei&fq=types:(HWCV_10002,HWCV_10000)"
  },
  "schema": "http://localhost:64930/v1/spec/schema.healthwise.api.items.json",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "HWCV_04520",
      "label": "Weight Loss Medicines",
      "types": [
        {
          "id": "HWCV_10002",
          "label": "Treatment"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "HWCV_22136",
      "label": "Weight Loss (Bariatric) Surgery",
      "types": [
        {
          "id": "HWCV_10002",
          "label": "Treatment"
        }
      ]
    }, etc, etc.
```

Now here's the response I get after converting it to a string:

```
{"status":200, "links":{"self":"https://search.healthwise.net/v1/suggestions?q=wei\u0026fq=types:HWCV_10002,HWCV_10000)"},"schema":"https://search.healthwise.net/v1/spec/schema.healthwise.api.items.json","items":[]}
```

My question is: How do I find (and list) the "items" array?  Or is it really empty because when I use android studio debugger to look at the jsonobject (after making the response a string and then loading it into a jsonobject) the array ([]) or whatever is empty:

```
0 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntry@4317} "status" -> "200"

1 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntry@4318} "links" -> "{"self":"https:\/\/search.healthwise.net\/v1\/suggestions?q=wei&fq=types:(HWCV_10002,HWCV_10000)"}"

2 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntry@4319} "schema" -> "https://search.healthwise.net/v1/spec/schema.healthwise.api.items.json"

3 = {LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntry@4320} "items" -> "[]"
 key = "items"
 value = {JSONArray@4328} "[]"
  values = {ArrayList@4333}  size = 0
```

BTW here's the code:

```
try {
        Response response = client.newCall(newRequest).execute();
        String jsonData = response.body().string();
        JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        final String str = jobject.getString("items");
        JSONArray jsonArray = jobject.getJSONArray("items");
        Log.d("OKHTTP3", "Got the response");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("OKHTTP3", "Exception while doing request");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I think that server really returns you an empty array. In this case, the problem is with your request parameters (server returns empty array for your specific request), or the server is broken in general.